# Inkscape PDF import. "tspan" element attributes

Tags: pdf, svg, import, inkscape

After importing the PDF file, the tspan elements have the X and Y attributes. These attributes unnecessary and interfere with the correct positioning of the element. How I can they be removed automatically in Inkscape? Without manual editing of the svg code.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need clear two attribute "x" and "y" in "tspan" element. Not manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic18cd-2.html?t=18972

- Edit > Select Same > Object Type (Alt-Shift-A)
- Text > Remove Manual Kerns